# Info panel below TRs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have a table, and I'd like to add a hideable/showable panel below each row for more controls and info than can reasonably fit in the table row. My first thought was to have a sibling tr for each original tr, and put a single td inside with an appropriate colspan:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    ...
  <tr>
  <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
    <td colspan="4">...</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
```

Each original row would have a button that would hide() or show() the corresponding tr, and the td in the child row would have all the extra controls that don't need to be seen normally.

This gets tricky because I'm using d3 to build the table, and d3 doesn't like multiple elements per datum (see [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746252/how-to-create-multiple-adjacent-nodes-per-data-element-with-d3-js-selections) and [this other thing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/WDcyoZ8cZiY)).

It's also tricky because I'm using [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), which sorts the table client-side using the values in tds, so the original data has to stay in table format. (It could keep pairs of rows together using a css class "tablesorter-childRow".) I also don't believe I can have multiple tbodies because they aren't sorted along with rows -- each tbody's rows are sorted.

I thought about using jquery afterwards to insert a tr after each original tr, but then d3 won't update the table properly when something changes (since the data won't join properly), and the reason I'm using d3 is because it makes building lots of dom elements easier (for me at least).

So, question time: how else can I create this panel that

1. moves with the original table rows
2. doesn't affect sorting
3. can be hidden or shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two sibling elements to share the same data, the easiest way in d3 is to group them under a parent element.  You assign the parent element the data, and then when you create its two child elements (without assigning data) they both inherit the parent's data.

In SVG, the usual parent element is a `<g>`.  For your purpose, the natural parent element would be [`<tbody>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) which can be used to group table rows.  ***However, you'd have to modify the table sorting code that you're using, to sort individual `<tbody>` elements instead of individual rows.***

The only other option would be to dynamically set the content of the info row and insert it in the correct place every time you want to show it, similar to how many tooltip examples work: it's the same tooltip, just moved around and with new data.  If you're using d3 to attach the event handler on the table rows, it will pass the data object of the clicked-on row to the event handling function, so you can use that data to fill the information content without creating a data-join.  To insert the info row after the clicked `<tr>` element, you could use [d3's `insert()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert) function, but the format isn't ideal; better to use [plain Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) or JQuery.  You'd also have to remove the info row before running your sort.

```
tableRows.on("click", showInfo);
/* remember to give your rows a tabIndex, so that keyboard users can 
   trigger the click action */

/* Create the persistent info box */
var infoRow = d3.select( document.createElement("tr") )
            //create a new <tr>, unattached to the document
                .attr("class", "infoBox";//set class to allow unique formatting

infoRow.append("td") //add a <td> within the <tr>
       .attr("colspan", colNames.length); //set to fill all columns


/* Show the info row for a clicked element */
function showInfo(d,i) {

    /* Hide info box if currently shown */
    infoRow.style("display", "none");

    /* Set content to match clicked row */
    infoRow.select("td") //select the <td> element
           .html(/* create html from the d object
                    you don't need a function(d), just
                    concatenate the string. */)

    /* Insert the row in the correct place.
       This will automatically remove it from any current location */
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(infoRow, this.nextSibling);
       //"this" is the tableRow object that received the click event

    infoRow.style("display", null); 
       //revert to default display setting (i.e. table-row)
}

function sort(/*parameters*/) {
     infoRow.remove(); 
     //remove the infoRow element from the document, 
     //so it only exists as a Javascript object again

     /* Run your sort code */
}
```